# Pebble SDK compile error, having to do with resource's

Tags: pebble-sdk

When I compile I get this error, I have added the font to the resources and set its identifier as RESOURCE_ID_FONT_UNICODE_16, what am I doing wrong?

../src/Timely.c:1395:59: error: 'RESOURCE_ID_FONT_UNICODE_16' undeclared (first use in this function)

Answer (score 0):

All right I found 2 problems one the identifier should've just been FONT_UNICODE_16 and also when I downloaded the fonts off of gethub I did in such a way to corrupt them.